# question about moving grphic

Tags: functions

suppose there is two  point A and B   they are connected by straight railway  line on which there is moving locootive 
on figure a there is shown time graphic with relative distance S_A  from  point A till locoo[image]tive

from figure B we should choose which one is graphic  of the in the same process  that express graph of   time-distance relation from the B point to locootive   measure S_B distance
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about this: If points A and B are, say, 3 km apart, then the distance from A to the train plus the distance from the train to B should always be 3 km. For example, if the train is 1 km from A, then it is 2 km from B. If it is 2 km from A, then it is 1 km from B. Which of the choices for graphs of S_B has the property that, for all times t, the value S_A(t) + S_B(t) is the same constant throughout?